# How to prepare Debian packages of software built with `bmake`

Tags: debian, package-managers, bsdmake

I am porting some software to Debian/Jessie which uses `bmake`, the version of `make` usually found on BSDs, as build system.  So the installation procedure is

```
 ./configure
 bmake all
 bmake install
```

Aside from the use of `bmake` instead of `make`, it is pretty canonical.  Which packaging method should I use? There is several package preparation frameworks on Debian and it is hard for the casual packager to keep an eye on this.

Comment: Are there features in the Makefile which are unavailable on GNU make? If not, just use that.

Comment: BSD Make and GNU Make are essentially incompatible, so the answer to your question is *YES*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could put `Build-Depends: bmake` and hack your `debian/rules` to use that instead if you feel you really have to. I don't think Debhelper would make this hard at all so we are talking maybe two lines of override in your `debian/rules`.